# How to convert a List<String[]> of Subtitle Structure to HashMap<String, List<String[]>>

Tags: java, loops, hashmap

I have a table that show a Subtitle structure that was sorted in a right order from 1, 2, 3..... TitleID is unique.

```
TitleID - Title - Level - Order
451 - History - Level1 - 1
123 - History of America - Level2 - 2
465 - History of Cali - Level3 - 3
578 - History of NewYork - Level3 - 4
765 - History of Europe - Level2 - 5
754 - History of West Europe - Level3 - 6
```

This table was converted into a `List<String[]>` of `{"451", "History", "Level1", "1" }`, `{"123", "History of America", "Level2", "2" }`... also in a right order.

I want to convert this `List<String[]>` into a `HashMap<String, List<String[]>>`. If i do it manually it should be like this:

```
HashMap<String, List<String[]>> titleHashMap = new HashMap<String, List<String[]>>();

List<String[]> subTitleList=new ArrayList<String[]>;
String[] titles1={"123", "History of America", "Level2"};
subTitleList.add(titles1);
String[] titles12={"765", "History of Europe", "Level2"};
subTitleList.add(titles12);
titleHashMap.put("451", subTitleList);

List<String[]> subTitleList2=new ArrayList<String[]>;
String[] titles2={"465", "History of Cali" , "Level3"};
subTitleList2.add(titles2);

String[] titles21={"578", "History of NewYork", "Level3"};
subTitleList2.add(titles21);

titleHashMap.put("123", subTitleList2);
```

But i don't want to do it manually, so how to do it automatically? 
Note: I also want a root level that parent of all Level1. Ex, `titleHashMap.put("root", subTitleListOfLevel1);`

Comment: Do it in `for-each` loop.

Comment: If the size of the string array: `{"123", "History of America", "Level2"}` is limited reflecting only a number of attribute why aren't you are going with OOP style ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example doesn't explain how the lessons are grouped and what should be the key of the map. I assume the lessons are grouped by level and the key will be the level. But you can adjust it easily.

```
// already exists:
List<String[]> lessons = ...

// final format
final HashMap<String, List<String[]>> titleHashMap = new HashMap<String, List<String[]>>();

for (String[] lesson : lessons) {
    final String level = lesson[2];
    if (!titleHashMap.containsKey(level)) {
        titleHashMap.put(level, new ArrayList<String[]>());
    }
    titleHashMap.get(level).add(lesson);
}
```